# how to display the page content in popup window?

Tags: plugins

Created Main Menu with 3 menu item(Home About,Apply Now),my task to display the content of "Apply now" page in a popup while clicking "Apply now" from menu?

Comment: its a wordpress site

Answer (score 1):

I use Plugin for display the page content in popup window

Check official website for [live demo](http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2012/05/25/wordpress-popup-plugin-anything-popup/)

**Plugin advantage**

-Easy to configuration.

-Unblockable.

-HTML Editor to add popup contact.

-Plugin supports Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE 7,8,9,10

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery library such as [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)  to open a pop-up modal which will display certain elements of a page ( ajax feature ).

For this you will have to add a jQuery click event handler to the "Apply Now" menu link which will call the FancyBox code.